# Categorization with multiple values- QGIS 2.18

Tags: style, fields-attributes, rule-based, qgis-2.18

I'm trying to represent 2 columns in polygon layer. I've tried to do it with the rule-based style but didn't understand how to do it. This is the attribute table of the polygon:

[image]

I've tried to use this expression:

[image]

but with no succses.

In ArcGIS I can do it with this option, so i can see in the legend both length and area data:

[image]

How can i do it in QGIS 2.18?

I also read:

- [QGIS rule-based categorization with multiple variables](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/175992/qgis-rule-based-categorization-with-multiple-variables)
- [QGIS: Categorized styling - by multiple columns](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/119995/qgis-categorized-styling-by-multiple-columns)

but didn't find any suitable answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, if i understood your question the answers is this:

You have to use "**GEOMETRY (AREA) || GEOMETRY (PERIMETER)**".

Step_1 - Layer > Properties > Style > Categorized > E = Insert Expression ( AREA || PERIMETER)> ok... (In this step you can add more Geometry if you have in your table)

[image]

Step_2 - classify > apply > Ok...

[image]

Step_3 - Legend (On Layers Panel).

[image]

Comment: please increase the screen shot

Comment: nop, i copied the expression to the Expression Dialog-nothing happend.

Comment: try this: "yourcolumn1" || "yourcolumn2" or $area || $perimeter for direct calculation. In Expression dialog you can browse your fileds and values or filter functions etx.

Comment: After the insert Expression you must "Classify" your "Categorized style"

Comment: i added : "nam2"  ||  "nam3"   but the how i make space between the two fields?   because the the words in the field (i used now different field with words) are attached.

Answer (score 5):

QGIS uses one apostrophe for python string expression. Concatenating two text fields should be done like this:

```
"FieldA" + ' ' + "FieldB"
```

There is a space between the two single apostrophes. 
You can also use sa,e principal for integer or decimal values, so long as you use `to_string()` before the field name.

Furthermore, you do not need to calculate a new field to use as a unique value for symbology, you can do that with the same expression above when used in conjunction with categorized style and expressions.
[image]

Comment: "FIELD 1"  ||  '  SPACE  ' ||  "FIELD2"

Answer (score 2):

I created one more column named **Space (text)** and insert into **__** .I tried to put **space** but it does not work. Maybe there´s another way.

[image]

**$area  ||  "Space"  ||  $perimeter**

Comment: Your "Space" has double inverted commas. Try using 'Space'     ie: Single inverted comma's.....In expressions, double inverted commas are often used for reference to a fieldname. In you rexample, you are attempting to reference a field called "Space"